# Angular Universal Uncaught (in promise): Error: NotYetImplemented Error

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-universal

When I try to build my Angular universal app it displays the below error in a terminal window. I have tried various aspects but nothing looks good till now. Can anyone suggest how can identify the root cause of the below error? Because it's a more generic error and I don't have any idea to look at any specific thing due to this generic error. Any help will be much appreciated as I am trying to resolve this for a long today.

````
Error: NotYetImplemented
    at Object.exports2.nyi (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:97:140065)
    at getWebGLContext (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:6:175775)
    at isSoftwareRendering (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:6:175991)
    at Module.57425 (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:6:516353)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:8145:971155)
    at Object.39093 (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:1:654211)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:8145:971155)
    at Object.33366 (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:1:807688)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:8145:971155)
    at Object.13754 (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:1:804775)
    at resolvePromise (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:1284:4397)
    at resolvePromise (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:1284:3367)
    at D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:1284:6112
    at _ZoneDelegate2.invokeTask (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:1268:11819)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:4690:3154)
    at _ZoneDelegate2.invokeTask (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:1268:11709)
    at Zone3.runTask (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:1268:4295)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:1268:15594) {
  rejection: Error: NotYetImplemented
      at Object.exports2.nyi (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:97:140065)
      at getWebGLContext (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:6:175775)
      at isSoftwareRendering (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:6:175991)
      at Module.57425 (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:6:516353)
      at __webpack_require__ (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:8145:971155)
      at Object.39093 (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:1:654211)
      at __webpack_require__ (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:8145:971155)
      at Object.33366 (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:1:807688)
      at __webpack_require__ (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:8145:971155)
      at Object.13754 (D:\Project\Project\ClientPortal\dist\ClientPortal\server\main.js:1:804775),
  promise: ZoneAwarePromise [Promise] {```
````

Answer (score 2):

you are using a third party library in your app that doesn't support ssr. you have to add this code every where you use this library:

```
isBrowser = false;
constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId){
isBrowser  = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
}
```

in your html file:

```
<thirdparty *ngIf="isBrowser"></thirdparty>
```

if you use it in your typescript:

```
if (this.isBrowser) {
   ...
}
```